# Where to place std_lib_facilities.h header file?

Tags: c++, header

I'm just getting started with programming and am using Stroustrup's book: "Programming: Principles and Practice using C++ (Second Edition)" and cannot figure out where this std_lib_facilities.h needs to go for Linux users. I find it kind of odd that he offers only help for Windows users who use Visual Studios.

I searched where the c++ files are under /usr/include/c++ and noticed that I have two c++'s: 5.4.0 and 5. Why is that exactly? I am not sure if I need to add the std_lib_facilities.h file in either of these two folders.

Nonetheless I tried a couple ways to find a solution:

1. I made a project folder on my desktop and placed the source code and the std_lib_facilities.h file at the same level but I got a warning error.

   In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/ext/hash_map:60:0,
               from std_lib_facilities.h:34,
               from Hallo_Welt.cpp:1:
   /usr/include/c++/5/backward/backward_warning.h:32:2: warning: 
   warning This file includes at least one deprecated or antiquated 
   header which may be removed without further notice at a future date. 
   Please use a non-deprecated interface with equivalent functionality 
   instead. For a listing of replacement headers and interfaces, consult 
   the file backward_warning.h. To disable this warning use -Wno-
   deprecated. [-Wcpp]
   warning \
2. Next I made the header file at a subdirectory of the project folder under "header". That didn't work either and I got this error:

   g++ Hallo_Welt.cpp
   Hallo_Welt.cpp:1:10: error: #include expects "FILENAME" or 
   include std_lib_facilities.h
            ^
   Hallo_Welt.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
   Hallo_Welt.cpp:4:2: error: ‘cout’ was not declared in this scope
   cout<<"Hallo Welt\n";

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm using Vim by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just place the header file in the same folder as the executable and include it:

```
// assumes this file is named hello_world.cpp

#include "std_lib_facilities.h"

int main()
{
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Then build using:

```
g++ hello_world.cpp
```

This will build the executable as `a.out` in the same folder. To specify another binary name, use the `-o` parameter:

```
g++ hello_world.cpp -o hello_world
```

To prevent needing to copy the header into multiple folders for each chapter (assuming you use such folder management), you can place it in an `include` folder at the same level, like so:

```
+ ~/learn_cpp/
|
+--+ ch01/
|  |
|  +--- hello_world.cpp
|
+--+ include/
   |
   +--- std_lib_facilities.h
```

Then from inside `hello_world.cpp`, you'd include it with the relative path like so:

```
#include "../include/std_lib_facilities.h"
```

This keeps it simple and prevents adding it to your headers globally on your system. You'll be discontinuing your use of this header in a few chapters, anyways.

Answer (score 0):

What you have done in **1** is sensible; you should not place any of your own source code (and Stroustrup's courseware falls into that category) in the c++ compiler's installation directories.

The message is simply a warneng to tell you that the header (`std_lib_facilities.h`) references old code. You can safely ignore it for now. If you search online for `std_lib_facilities.h` you'll likely find a newer version of the file.

As for why there are two `/usr/include/c++`  directories, it is to allow for different versions of the compiler, following updates for example, to coexist. You can discover the path that `g++` searches for include files by typing `gcc -xc++ -E -v -` at a command prompt.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but thanks for the clarification. It makes sense now and everything works.